# Printing a multi byte integer in binary format

Tags: c

I want to print a given integer in a binary format. I saw this example below and tried it, but I did not get the correct output for a multi-byte integer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define BYTETOBINARYPATTERN "%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d"
#define BYTETOBINARY(byte)\
(byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x40 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x20 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x10 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x08 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x04 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x02 ? 1 : 0), \
(byte & 0x01 ? 1 : 0)

int main(){
   // int a = (sizeof(int)*8);
    int a = 10;
    int m = 257; // takes two bytes
    /* For a Single byte integer */
    printf(BYTETOBINARYPATTERN"\n",BYTETOBINARY(a));
    /* For a multibyte integer */
    printf("M : "BYTETOBINARYPATTERN","BYTETOBINARYPATTERN"\n",BYTETOBINARY(m>>8),BYTETOBINARY(m));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
00001010
M : 00000001,00000001
```

Comment: Your output is correct - 257 in binary is `0000000100000001`, which is exactly what your program prints. Voting to close as non-reproducible typo. Please unaccept my answer so that I could delete it.

Comment: I have un-checked the answer